# proper usage of up and down keys for checking up and down arrows

Tags: bash

I am facing an issue during the usage of up and down on gnome-terminal.
Lets say my previous commands are

```
vi pos_of_rightmost_setbit.cpp 
gcc -o harsha pos_of_rightmost_setbit.cpp
```

At this point when I press a up arrow,I see last previous command `gcc -o harsha pos_of_rightmost_setbit.cpp` which is perfect.

But when I hit up arrow again,I have to see last but one previous command which is `vi pos_of_rightmost_setbit.cpp`, Instead I am seeing `gcc -o harvightmost_setbit.cpp`.

When I hit enter at this point of time,The command vi pos_of_rightmost_setbit.cpp is working fine,So I think there some problems with bashrc settings.

I am attaching screenshots for better understanding.
[image: For previous command]

[image: For last but one previous command]

Comment: run `history` to see the cmd list you've executed.

Comment: This sounds like a terminal type or prompt setting problem causing redraw issues. Does hitting `ctrl-l` after hitting `up` cause the right command to display correctly?

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes ctrl-l after hitting up is displaying the command properly..What might be the issue?

Comment: @Kent Yeah! history is working fine. In fact the command which is getting displayed wrongly is also working..The only problem I see is display.

Comment: What is your prompt (`$PS1`) set to? What is `$TERM` set to?

Comment: @EtanReisner PS1="\e[1;39m[\u@\h \W]\$ \e[m"  I have seen this issue after adding this.I have seen the behavior after commenting this.It looks fine then.What might be the issue?Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That prompt string is exactly the problem.

You need to surround every non-printing bit of that prompt string with `\[` and `\]` to tell readline not to count them in the length of the prompt.

So you should have something like `PS1="\[\e[1;39m\][\u@\h \W]\$ \[\e[m\]"`.

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/301353/escape-non-printing-characters-in-a-function-for-a-bash-prompt/301355#301355